# Creating Android MessageBox without context or Activity?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Is there any way to create a messageBox in android without passing some context? I need it for debugging purposes. I use phonegap and I have a custom plugin implemented in java and called by javascript which is linked through phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating it with null content?

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(this.cordova.getActivity(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

(note `Toast.makeText` is probably the wrong example because it does not run in background threads, but the approach is probably still valid.)

from common pitfalls section at [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html)

> Plugins do not have direct access to the Context as they have in the past. The legacy ctx member is deprecated, and will be removed six months after 2.0 is released. All the methods that ctx has exist on the Context, so both getContext() and **getActivity**()` are capable of returning the proper object required.